# Performance Testing # how can i test large number of users?

Tags: performance, jmeter, performance-testing

i have issue in testing large number of users.
so what i tried is i tryied x capacity of instance with x number of users.

now my questin is #

if i have cpu with x capacity and i tested with jmeter and it can handle 100 users without
any issues.

so should i consider this ?

so what i tried is #
if x capacity can handle 100 user
x2 capacity can handle  200 users

and x10 cpacity will require for 1000 users ? and so on
cos in practically it will not be possible to handle large number of user ?

what will be best approach to get this data ?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can predict/extrapolate it this way, in order to get the accurate results you need to run your test against the production environment (or exact replica of the production environment)

Also CPU isn't necessarily the [bottleneck](https://www.quora.com/What-is-bottleneck-in-performance-testing) as the breaking/slowest point could be something different like:

- lack of RAM
- inefficient algorithms which don't fully utilize the available CPU power
- slow disks
- [slow database queries](https://orangematter.solarwinds.com/2018/01/17/slow-queries-move-fast-to-fix-them/)

So only a [profiler tool](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_performance_analysis_tools) or an [APM tool](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application_performance_management) can tell you where is the bottleneck, check out [Performance Testing in Scaled Down Environments. Part One: The Challenges](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/performance-testing-scaled-down-environments-part-one-challenges) for more comprehensive explanation if needed.

Comment: then practicall how you will test your system agains all numbers ?